# what is the limit for the # of returned objects in graph.facebook.com/me/likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get ALL user likes at once without pagination.

I could hit: graph.facebook.com/me/likes ...however, is there a limit to the # of objects returned by facebook? if so, what is that limit and can it be overwritten?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default limit is something like 25 results. You can specify a limit by providing a limit parameter to facebook:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?limit=100
```

Checkout the [API Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) under the heading "Paging".

That said, there's never a guarantee that you'll get all the likes at once, even if you set the `limit` parameter to be greater than or equal to the number of likes on an object.

On top of that, **you'll often find that the number of likes reported on the Facebook website or by the Graph API is higher than what you can get by fetching the `/likes` connection in the Graph API**. I'm trying (and failing) to find the SO question that talked about why that is, but if I remember right that number sometimes includes shares and other actions, not just likes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the pagination to page thru all the data that the Graph API can return.